# $P( \text{ no health issues }| \text{ sees doctor })$

Tags: conditional-probability

Example question ([taken from here](https://www.statisticshowto.com/total-probability-rule/)): 80% of people attend their primary care physician regularly; 35% of those people have no health problems crop up during the following year. Out of the 20% of people who don’t see their doctor regularly, only 5% have no health issues during the following year. What is the probability a random person will have no health problems in the following year?

In the first table, they say that $P(\text{ sees doctor } | \text{ no health issues }) = 0.35$. However, this is not true. It's supposed to be $P( \text{ no health issues }| \text{ sees doctor }) = 0.35$, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote events: $A$ is 'attending health care' and $B$ is 'having no health issues the following year'. We know that $P(A)=0.8, ~~ P(B|A)=0.35, ~~ P(B|\bar{A})=0.05)$.

According to the complete probability rule, $P(B)=P(B|A)* P(A) + P(B|\bar{A})* P(\bar{A})=0.35*0.8+0.05*0.2=0.29$.

Now, using Bayes:
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}=0.35*0.8/0.29=0.966$$

So the answer to your question is **yes**, you are right and the table is incorrectly labelled.